# Using AT FIRST to initialise loop variables

Tags: loops, abap, internal-tables

It seems like the `AT FIRST` statement of control level processing is ideal for any commands that have to be run or variables that have to be initialised before the loop itself starts running. Given how `AT` commands clear columns in the work area it's one of the few uses I still see for them.

To illustrate, rather than doing this:

```
CLEAR lv_loopcounter.
LOOP AT lt_itab INTO ls_wa.
    ADD 1 TO lv_loopcounter.
    ...
ENDLOOP.
```

We could do this:

```
LOOP AT lt_itab INTO ls_wa.
    AT FIRST.
        CLEAR lv_loopcounter.
    ENDAT.
    ADD 1 TO lv_loopcounter.
    ...
ENDLOOP.
```

Here it's immediately obvious that the variable needs to be initialised for the loop to function as intended. It also makes for cleaner looking code when you have a lot of statements that need to be run prior to a loop. The only downside I see is that it moves code inside a `LOOP` statement when it logically shouldn't be.

Is there a best practice here? Are there hidden caveats I should be aware of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both variants are possible, but they are semantically different: In the first version, the command `CLEAR` is executed unconditionally, in the first version, it is only executed if `lt_itab` contains at least one line. For the actual loop implementation, the difference is irrelevant, but for an empty table, the value of the variables in question differs after the `ENDLOOP` statement is reached. This is not a problem as long as you handle empty tables sensibly... :-)

The only other micro-caveat of the second version is that `AT FIRST` will clear all non-character fields of `ls_wa` and set all character fields of `ls_wa` to '*'.

Answer (score 6):

While vwegert's answer is correct for the simple loop case I've described in my question, there is a very important secondary case where `AT FIRST` will **not** function as you might expect, and that is when looping with a condition.

As SAP's `AT` documentation states:

> The control level is defined by the first row of the internal table. The control break takes place when this row is read.

In other words, `AT FIRST` will not fire on the first iteration of the loop but when *the absolute first row of the internal table* is read. What this means is that if we loop over only a few rows of an internal table, the odds are that we won't loop over the first row. If that is the case the control block will **not** be entered.

As an example:

```
LOOP AT lt_itab INTO DATA(ls_itab) WHERE itab_col1 = iv_value.
    AT FIRST.
        CLEAR lv_loopcounter.
    ENDAT.
    ADD 1 to lv_loopcounter.
    ...
ENDLOOP.
```

If `itab_col1` of the first internal table row matches `iv_value`, the loop counter will be cleared. If the first row's does not match this value, the loop counter will **not** be cleared!